# Change properties of a runtime created material which has been instantiated from asset bundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

We are loading our assets from an asset bundle. everything is contained on the asset bundle.
We have a material with name of **light_bulb_tex** in our asset bundle. we have wrote a shader , here is the shader code , (this material uses this shader):

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "Porject/FX/ColorDimmer" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color",Color)=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
        _OffColor ("OffColor",Color)=(0.772, 0.772, 0.772)
        _Intensity("Intensity",Range (0, 1))=0
    }

    CGINCLUDE

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        uniform fixed4 _Color;
        uniform fixed4 _OffColor;
        uniform fixed _Intensity;
        half4 _MainTex_ST;

        struct v2f {
            half4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        v2f vert(appdata_full v) {
            v2f o;

            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);    
            o.uv.xy = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);

            return o; 
        }

        fixed4 frag( v2f i ) : COLOR {  
            fixed4 texColor= tex2D (_MainTex, i.uv.xy) ;
            //fixed4 colorWithIntensity = 
            return lerp(_OffColor,_Color,_Intensity);
        }

    ENDCG

    SubShader {
    Tags{ "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }

    Pass {

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest 

        ENDCG

        }

    } 
    FallBack Off
}
```

shader is also included in the asset bundles, also it has been added to the list of **"Always Included shaders"** of the game. hence we have added the ColorDimmer shader to our project.

So when we have downloaded the asset bundles, by this piece of code , we are going to instantiate the game objects. the material are added to instantiated game objects by asset bundle automatically.

```
...
/* objectRenderer.material is added to the _instancedGameObject 
from asset bundle. here we want to create
copy of this material. so newMaterial is
just copy of objectRenderer.material with 
it's specific shader (loading from app), in this case ColorDimmer is the shader which will be added to the newMaterial. */

var objectRenderer = _instancedGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
var objectInAssetBundleMaterial = objectRenderer.material;
if (shaderName == "Proejct/FX/ColorDimmer")
{
    Material newMaterial = new Material(Shader.Find("Proejct/FX/ColorDimmer"));
    newMaterial.SetColor("_Color", objectInAssetBundleMaterial.GetColor("_Color"));
    newMaterial.name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    objectRenderer.material = newMaterial;
}
...
```

I don't know why **objectInAssetBundleMaterial.GetColor(_Color)** returns black. everything in inspector looks good, the material is loaded with the shader correctly. also the corresponding mat file in the asset bundle is defined in YAML like this:

```
 ....
    m_Colors:
    - _Color: {r: 0.8088235, g: 0.18436417, b: 0.18436417, a: 1}
    - _EmissionColor: {r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 1}
    - _OffColor: {r: 0.77205884, g: 0.77205884, b: 0.77205884, a: 1}
```

You can see that **_Color** is not black.

How can I call GetColor to get the value of _Color?

Comment: Could it be that you're getting ColorDimmer's colour? It's _Color is black (1,1,1,1).